# Error : Attempting to parse xml with using python and Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: java, python, xml-parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am so much struggling to parse xml file with using python and stanford CoreNLP. What I want to do is analyzing nlp.txt with Stanford Core NLP and output it to xml file. My code is here :

```
import os
import subprocess
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

fname = 'nlp.txt'
fname_parsed = 'nlp.txt.xml'


def parse_nlp():


    '''Analyze nlp.txt with Stanford Core NLP and output it to xml file.
     Do not execute if result file already exists.
    '''
    if not os.path.exists(fname_parsed):

        # Execute StanfordCoreNLP, output standard error to parse.out
        subprocess.run(
            'java -cp "/usr/local/lib/stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09/*"'
            ' -Xmx2g'
            ' edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP'
            ' -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref'
            ' -file ' + fname + ' 2>parse.out',
            shell=True,     # execute with shell
            check=True      # error check
        )


# analyze nlp.txt
parse_nlp()

# parse xml of result
root = ET.parse(fname_parsed)

# take only word
for word in root.iter('word'):
    print(word.text)
```

Then, I obtained standard error like :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stanford.py", line 30, in <module>
    parse_nlp()
  File "stanford.py", line 25, in parse_nlp
    check=True      # error check
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 418, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'java -cp "/usr/local/lib/stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09/*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref -file nlp.txt 2>parse.out' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Although I think that I am stuck to parse file, I cannot understand what is happening and how could I solve this issue. 
I am relatively beginner coding and just moved into NLP analysis. 
If it is explained in detail, it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hope it's not too late : p

I was writing almost the same code as yours and meet the same problem.

After looking up the page [Using Stanford CoreNLP from the command line](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html#quick-start),
I find that `-Xmx2g` was used to specify 2GB memory for the java subprocess.
Although my MBP only has 8G memory, I changed `-Xmx2g` to `-Xmx3g`. And it worked!

Comment: Alright ! Thank you for sharing your solution. I will try it later as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your java command is not properly entered into `subprocess.run()`.  If you create a string that is the full java command and use that as the first argument to `subprocess.run()` it should work.

Documentation for command line:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html

Comment: If you are still getting an error you should verify that command works on the command line.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, in other words, do you mean to read xml file with python ?

Comment: Have you been able to get this command to work on the command line and in a Python script by calling it with subprocess?  command: 'java -cp "/usr/local/lib/stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09/*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref -file nlp.txt 2>parse.out'

Comment: So you haven't been able to get it working in a Python script?  If so, I suggest just making a string that is the full command, and doing subprocess(cmd_string,shell=True) and see if that works